# Error "Invalid CSS after \"...inear-gradient(\": expected selector, was \"{\"",

Tags: css, npm, sass, compilation

Trying to compile sass i get this error: (can't find the wrong syntax:)

```
/* {
   "status": 1,
   "file": "C:/Users/faido/Desktop/Productivity/sass 
   css/project/sass/main.sass",
   "line": 36,
   "column": 9,
   "message": "Invalid CSS after \"...inear-gradient(\": expected selector, 
   was \"{\"",
   "formatted": "Error: Invalid CSS after \"...inear-gradient(\": expected 
   selector, was \"{\"\n        on line 36 of sass/main.sass\n>>         
   linear-gradient( {\n\n   --------^\n"
   }
*/
```

for this code:

```
.header 
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
        to right bottom, 
        rgba( $color-primary-light, 0.8 ), 
        rgba( $color-primary-dark, 0.8 )
    ),
    url(../img/hero.jpg)
```

Any help/insight is greatly apprectiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass's indented syntax [unfortunately does not support multiline expressions](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216).

To fix it, you'll have to put everything on one line:

```
.header 
    background-image:  linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba($color-primary-light, 0.8), rgba($color-primary-dark, 0.8)) url(../img/hero.jpg)
```

Comment: First of all thank you. I'm a sass newbie. is there no way of structuring these in a more aesthetically pleasing way. I hate having to scroll horizontally... do i have to switch to scss?

Comment: I don't think there is, I personally prefer the Scss syntax over the indented one and fortunately it does have multiline support, so I guess if you wanna do it in a prettier way you'll have to switch. It should be trivial to do though.